# Cannot get mouse pointer information from mousemove event

Tags: dart, polymer, dom-events, dart-polymer, mousemove

In normal JS Polymer, I can do something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/B5coRg):

```
<dom-module id="my-module">
  <template>
    <div on-mousemove="mousemove">Text here!</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-module',

      mousemove: function (event) {
        console.log(event);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This will print a mouse movement event containing the coordinates of the mouse pointer.

However, consider the following Dart project:

### pubspec.yaml

```
name: example
description: "stuff here"
version: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.18
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  browser: ^0.10.0
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
```

### web/index.dart

```
library photon.index;

import 'package:example/test.dart';

export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
```

### web/index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
</head>
<body unresolved>
  <my-module></my-module>

  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
```

### lib/test.dart

```
@HtmlImport('test.html')
library example.test;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;

@PolymerRegister('my-module')
class MyModule extends PolymerElement {
  MyModule.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  void mousemove(event, [_]) {
    print(event);
  }
}
```

### lib/test.html

```
<dom-module id="my-module">
  <template>
    <div on-mousemove="mousemove" id="target">Text here!</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

This is roughly equivalent to the JavaScript version. However, this will instead print an instance of `CustomEventWrapper`, which lacks the information on where the cursor is located. Is there some way to access the mouse pointer information?

Comment: What do you get from `print(event)`, `print(event.runtimeType)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `Instance of 'CustomEventWrapper'` and `CustomEventWrapper`, respectively. Also, I already tried `print(event.detail)`, it's always `0` (of type `int`), no matter where I move the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
  @reflectable
  void mousemove(CustomEventWrapper event, [_]) {
    MouseEvent mouseEvent = event.original;
    print('x: ${mouseEvent.client.x}');
    print('y: ${mouseEvent.client.y}');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the docs for `CustomEventWrapper`, but I somehow missed the `original` property.